# Wordpress Search query with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I am building a custom page where search query has mulitple values to compare like:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE table_item LIKE ('apple,banana')
```

I want to fetch multiple values with single query.

Comment: you can use IN instead of LIKE               where IN ('apple','banana')

Comment: but IN operator can accept %apple% this keyword because apple is not fix keyword. in before or after any word can be connect like applejam

Comment: so you can go for like and or as second ans of @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `WHERE IN (...)`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE table_item IN ('apple', 'banana')
```

If you really intended to use the `LIKE` operator to find those fruit names anywhere in the `table_item` column, then you probably intended to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE table_item LIKE '%apple%' OR table_item LIKE '%banana%'
```

If you don't want to have multiple `LIKE` clauses, then a third option would be to use `REGEXP` with a regex containing an alternator:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE table_item REGEXP 'apple|banana'
```

Here is a demo for this third option: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc3f9b/1

Comment: i will use this in other functions.

Answer (score 1):

check This.

```
   SELECT * from table WHERE table_item in ('apple','banana')
```